# Parse.com cloud code check user before allowing login

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am using the following code to allow login from my iOS and Android apps.  One of our paying customers has hundreds of users (who all use the same domain in their email i.e @mycompany.com) who need to be stopped from using the app immediately.

I cannot re-publish the client app as it takes time for review etc. How can I prevent login from a certain group of users from cloud code.

```
 Parse.User.logIn(user.username.toLowerCase(), user.password, {
          success: function(user) {

            user.set("platform", ionic.Platform.device());
            user.set("os", ionic.Platform.platform());
            user.save(null, {
              success: function(user) {
                console.log('ok');
              },
              error: function(err) {
                console.log('error setting device');
              }
            });
```

Is there is `beforeSave` on the session class?

Comment: I would create a new Role and give it access to Read only to the database or not even Read... and when new user is saved I would assign this Role to him so he wont be able to write to DB

Comment: do you have an access to the user email in this cloud code function ?

Comment: That's not a cloud function.